# Provider NotifyListeners not updating consumers

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm pretty new to flutter and really, really want to use provider to pass data around, but I just can't get it to work.   I think I have everything set right, but for some reason when I notify listeners, my app doesn't refresh.  All I'm trying to do is update a profile pic.  I start with a pic that is in firebase (works fine).  Then I give the user the option to update their pic with camera or photos.  When they choose a new pic, the consumer doesn't update like I would expect it to.   Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong or how I may be able to accomplish this?

First, here is my main:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Storage>(create: (context) => Storage()),
        StreamProvider<Uid>.value(value: AuthService().user),   
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(   ....
```

Then here is the class and method that updates the photo URL which I call from an image picker class.  I'm passing context so I can pop that image picker view and go back to the profile page after it's done.

```
class Storage with ChangeNotifier {
  String userPhotoUrl;
  void uploadImage(PickedFile _imageFile, BuildContext context) async {

      ....     //some other code here

      try {
        var snapshot =
            await _storage.ref().child('/profileImages/$_userId').putFile(file);

        await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          userPhotoUrl = value;
          notifyListeners();
          print(userPhotoUrl); //I know the code is working because it prints here
          Navigator.pop(context); 
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
     
      }
   }

}
```

And here is the profile page that I'm trying to update.  It's just not getting the updated value.

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  Profile({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> with TickerProviderStateMixin {


     String imageUrl;  //firebase pic to start - works fine

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

                       ....//some more widget tree

                 Consumer<Storage>(   
                  builder: (context, storage, widget) =>
                     CircularProfileAvatar(            //never updates. userPhotoURL always null
                        storage.userPhotoUrl ?? imageUrl, //always uses imageUrl,
                        elevation: 20,
                        borderColor: Colors.white70,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        radius: 50,
                         ),
                     ),
```

Any idea as to why it's not working?  I would think this should be easy but provider is still alluding me...

Comment: ```class Storage with ChangeNotifier``` should be ```class Storage extends ChangeNotifier```

Comment: How did you trigger the ```uploadImage()``` in from the view

Comment: @Toheeb, thanks for your suggestion, but extending ChangeNotifier didn't help.   I was using 'with' because I had originally extended Storage, then removed the extension and forgot to change.    uploadImage() is called from an ImageGrabber class.  So the flow is, user is on Profile page, then clicks a button which takes them to ImageGrabber page to choose camera or photos.  Then there is a button to upload which calls uploadImage() from Storage.  I'm passing the context to pop the ImageGrabber view and go back to Profile.

Comment: are you in anyway doing something like ```var storageNotifier = Provider.of<Storage>(context);``` then trigger upload like this ```storageNotifier.uploadImage()```?

Comment: no, I was using provider just to get the imageUrl, then when Provider.of wasn't working I switched to try Consumer but same thing.   I'm calling uploadImage() with a button press from a different Class.

Comment: 1. Ok that's a problem you need to do that because that's the only way to trigger that function from the ```ChangeNotifier``` you earlier provided in your multiple provider.

2. Maybe the reason my it's not working is you didn't put it directly under the build function e.g 
    ```Widget build(BuildContext context) {```
     ```var storageNotifier = Provider.of<Storage>(context);}```
3. If that's not the case please let me know the error you're getting

Comment: You haven't verified the answer you only voted it!

Comment: I didn't vote it up, unless maybe by accident.  I commented that it didn't work.   To answer your other question.  I do have Consumer under my Widget build.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong approach to solve the problem you need to do some like this

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<Storage>(
            create: (context) => Storage(),
            child: ImageGrabberScreen(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

When navigating to the screen you want to use the `Consumer()` widget

By using Provider or MultipleProvider as parent you're telling flutter you want to use `StreamBuilder()`widget but from your work I see you're using the `Consumer()` widget

Also try to do trigger your function doing the below

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 var storageNotifier = Provider.of<Storage>(context);
  ///In your button you can then do storageNotifier.uploadImage();
}
```

This type of problem is best solved with `FutureBuilder` if you don't have any form of button that is meant to trigger this event

```
Future<String> uploadImage() async {

  ....     //some other code here

    var snapshot =
        await _storage.ref().child('/profileImages/$_userId').putFile(file);

  return  await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  
}
```

Then somewhere in the widget tree do this

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: uploadImage(),
  builder: (_,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
       return CircularProfileAvatar(snapshot.data);
    }else{
     return CircularProfileAvatar(imageUrl);
    }
  })
 ...widget tree continues
```

Comment: this didn't change the results.  It still works same as before.  Thanks for suggestion though.  Anything else?

Comment: Ideally you should use a `FutureBuilder` to solve this problem I will update my answer.

Comment: I like the FutureBuilder suggestion, the initial button first takes me to a different view/class (ImageGrabber).  It's in imageGrabber that there is another button to use the picture which triggers uploadImage().  So how would you suggest I make that work with FutureBuilder?